# Page Response Time Shown by Mozilla Plugin FireBug

Tags: javascript

What a Wonderful website stackoverflow has been , promptly getting responses .

I have Created a Simple JSP Page which will retrive some Data From Datbase and shows it on to the FrontEnd .

When i used Mozilla plugin FireBug Profiler it showed these Values 10.3s (onload: 10.33s)

Could anybody please suggest me , what this Values actaully indicate ??

Thanks .

Answer (score 0):

Normally this shows time from the user hitting "go" to the time the last bit of data was sent to complete the page.